# PHP Split String After a Given String

Tags: php

I know the title is a little confusing but here is an example:

String: `SELECT * FROM tbl_clients ORDER BY updatedOn LIMIT 0,50`

What I want, is to take everything *after* `FROM` and put that into a new string.

So my resulting string would look like: `tbl_clients ORDER BY updatedOn LIMIT 0,50`

Is there any way to do his?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, doesn't `substr()` only split a string up between two given numbers?

Comment: Between 2 specified positions, between a specified position and the end of the string or between the beginning of a string and the specified position - read the manual pages

Comment: Right, but the position will always change since my string will usually be different.

Comment: @FastTrack Thats why you use `strpos()` to dynamically assess the position of your delimeter.

Comment: RTFM and you should be able to work out how to do this - strpos() tells you where to start

Comment: Thanks for explaining that out for me, Nick! I appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use [explode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) like so:

```
$string="SELECT * FROM tbl_clients ORDER BY updatedOn LIMIT 0,50";
$split=explode("FROM", $string, 2); 
//Restricts the split to 2 elements, i.e., everything after first occurrence goes in the second element

$result=$split[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Although the other answers on this page will work, I chose this one as it makes the most sense to me, personally.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
$mystring = "SELECT * FROM tbl_clients ORDER BY updatedOn LIMIT 0,50";
$spliter = "FROM ";
$splitstring = explode($spliter, $mystring);

$result = $splitstring[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of ways to do this (stripos-substr, explode), etc, but here's a **preg_split()** way:

```
$sql = 
    "SELECT * FROM tbl_clients ORDER BY updatedOn " .
    "WHERE `from`='something' LIMIT 0,50";
$r = preg_split( "/FROM /i", $sql );
print_r( $r );
```

Gives you $r[1] to play with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SELECT * 
    [1] => tbl_clients ORDER BY updatedOn WHERE `from`='something' LIMIT 0,50
)
```

There are some cases where preg_split can be uncommonly handy, like parsing an entire statement:

```
$r = preg_split( "/(SELECT)|(FROM)|(ORDER BY)|(WHERE)|(LIMIT)/i", $sql );
```

Gives you a neater breakdown in one statement:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] =>  * 
    [2] =>  tbl_clients 
    [3] =>  updatedOn 
    [4] =>  field='something' 
    [5] =>  0,50
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) your string on `FROM` to give you an array, then access the 1th element of the array.

```
$query_array = preg_split("/FROM /i", "SELECT a,b,d FROM tableA WHERE b=2", 1);
$table_and_clause = $query_array[1];  // "tableA WHERE b=2"...
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who can't read the appropriate manual pages for [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$string = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_clients ORDER BY updatedOn LIMIT 0,50';
$pos = strpos($string, ' FROM ');
$substring = substr($string, $pos + strlen(' FROM '));
```